# Use proc from inside another proc on TCL

Tags: tcl, vmd

I'm trying to write a script in tcl to execute some analysis on VMD. First I'm creating an atom selection inside a procedure, then I'm trying to use it on another procedure.

The atom selection from VMD is implemented as a Tcl function. The data returned from `atomselect` is the name of the function to use. You can read more [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.7.1/ug/node108.html).

When I create the atom selection outside a `proc` I can use it inside one just passing it as `global`. But now that I'm creating it inside one, when I try to use it it's just a string with the procedure name.

#### Resuming,

This works:

```
set all [atomselect top all]

proc test {} {
    global all
    $all num
}

test # Outuputs 7111
```

But this don't:

```
proc create {} {
    global all
    set all [atomselect top all]
}

proc test {} {
    global all
    $all num
}

create
test # Outputs -> invalid command name "atomselect1"
```

Comment: I assume it works if you put that `$all num` in the same procedure as the `atomselect`? Which would mean that we're talking _real_ shenanigans with scope binding, which is… severely unusual because it causes surprises like this.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes, it works inside the `create` procedure.

Comment: Thanks; that's enough for me to say what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the command created by the `atomselect` command is being deleted when the procedure returns. I *strongly* suspect that this is being done using a *local variable deletion trace* (on some variable that is otherwise unused). When `atomselect` is run in the global scope, there's no such natural deletion event (unless the global namespace is deleted, and that's an interpreter-ending event) so the trace never gets called and the created command persists indefinitely.

If we rewrite your create like this:

```
proc create {} {
    global all
    # Double quotes just because of the highlighting here
    set all [uplevel "#0" atomselect top all]
}
```

then the `atomselect` runs in the global scope (and the created command should persist) but all the rest of your code is in your procedure.

More properly, it should be done like this:

```
proc create {} {
    global all
    # Double quotes just because of the highlighting here
    set all [uplevel "#0" [list atomselect top all]]
    # Or this, to better show that we're talking about running a command:
    #   set all [uplevel "#0" [list \
    #       atomselect top all]]
}
```

This becomes far more important when you pass arguments with spaces (or other metasyntax characters) in, as `list` not only produces lists, but also substitution-free commands. (In fact, building commands and command fragments is absolutely one of the main uses of the `list` command; actual lists for ordinary data storage and manipulation tend to be made with some other command.)

Comment: The advantage of auto-deletion trickery like what `atomselect` uses is that it means that temporary commands get deleted automatically. If applications typically generate a lot of such commands, that can be quite a good memory saving for apps that follow the expected pattern. But you're not doing that…

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem, thanks for the answer and the lesson. I was really confused about how to use upvar on this.

Comment: Another bonus to using `list`: it uses a faster path in the Tcl code.